# Custom localization install4j

Tags: install4j

We are trying to build in Custom messages that would be shown to the User during the update process. To this end we have tried two approaches

1. Override message with an already existing key -> This works.
2. Have a Custom key/value pair in a separate .utf8 file -> This does not work as shown in the pictires below.

**Contents of .install4j directory**

[image]

**i4jparams.conf**

**Contents of i4j_extf_1_rn3phc.utf8**

updater.DownloadLocationLabel.Custom=Im nächsten Schritt wird das Installationsprogramm für die Aktualisierung heruntergeladen. Es wird empfohlen, mit der Installation des Updaters fortzufahren, da eine ältere Version des Clients möglicherweise nicht mit den neusten eingeführten Funktionen kompatibel ist.

**Updater where the contents are not reflected**

[image]

I would expect my Custom Key/Value pair to be picked up. Is there any other configurations that need to be taken care of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just got the text field syntax wrong, it should be

```
${i18n:updater.DownloadLocationLabel.Custom}
```